# How can I use error_log() with WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, error-logging

I'm trying to use `error_log()` in a custom WordPress plugin I am building but for some reason, I can't.

When I use `error_log()` my site just breaks, but I'm not seeing any errors in `debug.log`.

I have setup debugging in my `wp_config.php` file like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

Stranegly, if I use `error_log()` in my theme, the site doesn't break, but nothing is output to `debug.log` either.

What do I need to do to be able to use `error_log()` in my WordPress plugin and theme?

I'm using WordPress 3.9.1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY), `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` should be set to true by default, but it would seem that was not the case.

Adding `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);` to `wp_config.php` fixed the error logging.

Setting `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `false` removed the errors from the browser but allowed them to be output in the log.

It would seem that Wordpress requires `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY');` to output errors to the log whether you set it to be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 26):

## Update 2019

---

### Enable Debugging

You can simply enable debugging by adding the following code to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

There will be a `debug.log` file generated in your `wp-content` folder.

### Usage in production environment

If you want to log the errors without printing them in the frontend, add the following line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

This is really useful in production environments, since the page visitor will not be able to see your logs.

### Printing errors

Now you can just write to your log by using the `error_log` function:

```
error_log( 'Hello World!' );
```

Or pretty print your output by making use of the `print_r` method:

```
error_log( print_r( 'Hello World!', true ) );
```

> Pro Tip: If you're using the bash you can observe the log with `tail -f wp-content/debug.log`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. For me commenting out this line helped.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable WordPress logging adding this to `wp-config.php`:

```
 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

you can write to the log file using the [`error_log()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) provided by PHP.

Also, you can add the following code snippet in your `wp-config.php` file. It's very useful for debugging your WordPress site.

```
function write_log($log) {
    if (true === WP_DEBUG) {
        if (is_array($log) || is_object($log)) {
            error_log(print_r($log, true));
        } else {
            error_log($log);
        }
    }
}

write_log('THIS IS THE START OF MY CUSTOM DEBUG');
//i can log data like objects
write_log($whatever_you_want_to_log);
```